# Firebase authentication -Discarding data

Tags: firebase, authentication, android-studio-3.0

As a beginner i am first time trying to work with firebase ,although as per process i did every thing i don't know where i am going wrong.
I'm working in Android Studio 3.0.1

Here is my gradle build file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "courses.pluralsight.com.tabianconsulting"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
   }

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',  
  {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
   })

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After searching for long over the correct versions of sdk,firebase and google play service i am still unable to get it correct,tried combinaation and it isn't working .
Android SDK version 26.0.1
Google play service 46
Google repository 58

the error am getting is down below

```
        E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch
        E/FA: Failed to get app instance id
```

Please some one help me out!!

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: I tried it with real device and it is working fine ,but i am unable over an emulator.Also i tried changing my firebase version from 11.0.4 to 11.6.2 but its just working on real device and not on emulator ,so what i have to for it to work on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you need to go to your SDK manager and update your emulator to its latest version in order to support the firebase version you want to use.